# bin/cake doesn't create association

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-bake

I have 2 tables and I want to create association between them, however bin/cake doesn't do it correctly.

```
CREATE TABLE `teams` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `joiningID` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
     `name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
     `admin` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `created` datetime NOT NULL,
     `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     UNIQUE KEY `admin` (`admin`),
     UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
     CONSTRAINT `fk_admin` FOREIGN KEY (`admin`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

USERS:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `encrypted_password` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `salt` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `facebook_json` varchar(700) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `team` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
 KEY `users_ibfk_1` (`team`),
 CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`team`) REFERENCES `teams` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=168 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Whenever I do bin/cake bake it creates all classes but it doesn't create associations. Here is my part of my Team Entity and it has int $admin and not User Entity...

```
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $joiningID
 * @property string $name
 * @property int $admin
 * @property \Cake\I18n\FrozenTime $created
 * @property \Cake\I18n\FrozenTime $modified
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to use `bin\cake bake` to generate model, views and controllers.

CakePHP assumes that the foreign keys follows the following convention : `<singularized version of the table name>_id`. So in your case you should rename your `team` foreign key to `team_id`, and the relationships should be correctly detected.

So your `user` entity would have a belongsTo relationship with the `teams` table. CakePHP would then create a `team` variable in your entity to link to the associated `team` entity.

See : https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html